# What is the second largest eigenvalue of Perron matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $$
> \left[
> \begin{array}{@{}ccccc@{}}
> 0.9& 0.1& 0& 0& 0& 0& \\
> 0& 0.9& 0.1& 0& 0& 0& \\
> 0& 0& 0.9& 0& 0& 0.1& \\
> 0& 0& 0& 0.9& 0.1& 0& \\
> 0& 0& 0& 0.1& 0.9& 0& \\
> 0.1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0.9& \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> $$

This is a Perron (P) Matrix, in documents i read μ_2 is the second largest eigenvalue of P matrix. here what is the μ_2 or second largest eigenvalue.

Comment: I am sorry Jyrki I gave a wrong example i changed my matrix example.but i want ask an eigenvalue is a sum of a row or a column?

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately withot the circulant structure it is hard to tell what the eigenvalues are :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent comment and response, but I'll write them out explicitly.

For the new matrix, you have:

$\lambda_1 = 1$

$\lambda_2 = 1$

$\lambda_3 = 0.9 + 0.1 i$

$\lambda_4 = 0.9 - 0.1 i$

$\lambda_5 = 0.8$

$\lambda_6 = 0.8$

What do you mean by largest eigenvalue in this context? Do you mean in absolute value, in magnitude or using some other measure?

Comment: I mean absolute value but not largest ,largest 2nd eigenvalue..Could i ask how can you calculate λ1=1..λ6=0.8 ? Thank you so much

Comment: The standard way $|A -\lambda I| = 0$ and then solve for the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Regards

Comment: You are very welcome. Regards

Comment: Amzoti I wonder do you have knowledge about primitive matrix,if yes is this matrix is primitive?

Comment: Read the 1-st paragraph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem. If still not clear, this can be a new question on how to determine it. Regards

Comment: Nice feedback from the OP, and follow up from you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues); the Wikipedia article gives the eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: You are right it is my fault let me give a better example or edit the matrice.Thank you Joriki